# Get nearest paper size from the list of available paper size

Tags: c#, algorithm, logic

We have a pre-defined list of paper sizes, for e.g.

```
PageSize = PageSize.A3, Height = 297, Width = 420 
PageSize = PageSize.A4, Height = 210, Width = 297 
PageSize = PageSize.A5, Height = 148, Width = 210 
PageSize = PageSize.B4, Height = 257, Width = 364 
PageSize = PageSize.B5, Height = 182, Width = 257 
PageSize = PageSize.LETTER, Height = 216, Width = 279 
PageSize = PageSize.LEGAL, Height = 216, Width = 356 
PageSize = PageSize.TABLOID, Height = 279, Width = 432
```

I have to write a C# code to get the nearest paper size from the above list of entered paper size.

**What I have tried:**

```
matchedPageSize = (from item in pageSizeMap
                   where item.Width >= height
                   where item.Height >= width
                   let itemSum = item.Width * item.Height
                   let difference = Math.Abs((height * width) - itemSum)
                   orderby difference
                   select item).FirstOrDefault();

if(matchedPageSize == null)
{
   matchedPageSize = (from item in pageSizeMap
                      where item.Width < height
                      where item.Height < width
                      let itemSum = item.Width * item.Height
                      let difference = Math.Abs((height * width) - itemSum)
                      orderby difference
                      select item).FirstOrDefault();
  }
```

The above logic works well except in the two cases:

1. When height is less than all the above mentioned heights and width is more than all the above mentioned widths. For e.g. Height: 50, Width: 500
2. When height is more than all the above mentioned heights and width
   is less than all the above mentioned widths. For e.g. Height: 400, Width: 150

Request you to suggest the best possible logic for the above problem.

Comment: @Roma: Yes, this is the first case. Also the issue is with 500X100 size.

Comment: Check if(matchedPageSize == null) after 2nd selection. Now it will mean that there is no predefined sizes that cover user's area. But from you post it's not clear what to do in this case.

Comment: You need to define exactly what you the logic is for deciding which size to choose.  And then write the code

Comment: @Saket, See my answer. That solution should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the sum of differences between `Height` and `Width` of every size with test size(`someSize`).

Hepler:

```
int GetDifference(int a, int b)
{
    return Math.Abs(a - b);
}
```

Query for sorting sizes from the nearest to the most far:

```
var sorted = 
    pageSizeMap
    .OrderBy((s) => GetDifference(s.Height, someSize.Height) + GetDifference(s.Width, someSize.Width))
    .ThenBy((s) => Math.Abs(GetDifference(s.Height, s.Width) - GetDifference(someSize.Height, someSize.Width)));
```

To get the nearest size:

```
var nearest = sorted.ElementAt(0);
```

Comment: Let's say predefined dimensions(height, width) are 33,11 and 200, 100. And entered dimension(height, width) is 20,10. In this case, as per above logic, the nearest paper size will be 200,100; but the expected should be 33,11. Am I correct?

Comment: @Saket, yes, you are correct. The algorithm works in a wrong way. I will try another one. It is very interesting question for me)

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @Saket, if we have two dimensions (height, width): `34 10` and `33 11`. Which one should I choose for entered dimensions `20 10`?

Comment: I do understand your logic, but I was just wondering if order by with difference of areas would be fine. What do you think?

Comment: @Saket, I tried the solution with areas, but assume you have to `PageSizes` (height, width): `75 75` and `500 10` and you try to match size `100 50`. The areas are: `75 * 75 = 5625`, `500 * 10 = 5000` and the area of test size is `100 * 50 = 5000`. So, by areas the nearest is size `500 10`, but by dimensions - `75 75`

Comment: @Saket, my solution in answer has one disadvantage. I will make it better if you say that it works for you.

Comment: I haven't tested all the cases, but it works in most of them. Please refactor it if you have a better solution. Thanks.